# I keep getting an error in Python 3.9, anyone have a solution, its not taking in "import time" and "Lock"

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

```
from threading import Thread, Lock, current_thread
from queue import Queue
import time

def worker(q, Lock):
    while True:
        value = q.get()

        #processing...
        print(f'in {current_thread().name} got {value}')
        q.task_done()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    q = Queue()

    num_threads = 10

    for i in range(num_threads):
        thread = Thread(target=worker)
        thread.daemon=True
        thread.start()

    for i in range(1, 21):
        q.put(i)

    q.join()

    print('end main')
```

I keep getting an error in Python 3.9, anyone have a solution, its not taking in "import time" and "Lock"

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "its not taking." If you are asking for help understanding an error message, then please include the error message in your question.

Comment: One problem is obvious though: Your `worker` function requires two positional arguments, but you aren't providing any arguments when you create the thread.